# Unit testing REST API in laravel: basic authentication ignored

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

I want to test a small API with Basic Authentication.

Route looks like this :

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'auth.basic'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        return 'Hello';
    });
});
```

And the test looks like that:

```
class APITest extends TestCase {
    public function testHTTPAuthFailed()
    {
        $response = $this->call('GET', 'api/v1');
        fwrite(STDERR, print_r($response->getContent(), TRUE));
    }

}
```

When I run test with phpunit, I can see "Hello" in console. It's not what I excepted, I thought I will see "Authentication failed". But if I try to call my API with cURL (on a terminal), I can see Authentication failed (so it's ok, it's what I excepted):

```
$ curl -i host/api/v1
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

So why does phpunit in laravel (4.2) skip (?) basic authentication. How can I test invalid credentials ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've juste found an answer in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22581009/978690). I need to add : `Route::enableFilters();` in my test function and it's ok.